# How to edit a file inside a docker image without rebuilding the entire image?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, runtime-error

I have a huge Nodejs microservice with a huge code base(not mine), I am trying to build docker images and run them locally, but when I do that I see failures in my code like 
1st Error : was due to me adding a /**/ comment block in a json file 
2nd Error : Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined] [I know this is an error in my route ]

Question is how do I catch these errors before hand before building my docker Image , and in cases like the first error how can I directly replace the file in the docker image.

Answer (score 1):

create a new Dockerfile

```
FROM myimage:mytag
COPY new_file /path/file
```

in this way docker will use the already build image you have

**Other solution:**

create the container

```
docker create --name mycon myimage
```

copy the new file to it:

```
docker cp myfile mycon:/path/myfile
```

Comment: I already have Dockerfile will I not faces issues creating a new one?.